# Custom Flex charting datatip

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to emulate the datatip feature on google finance here - http://www.google.com/finance?q=INDE...EXNASDAQ:.IXIC

whereas the datatip does not appear over the chart when you hover over, but instead is anchored in the top right header of the chart. How do I go about doing this? Thx in advance!

tone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would do it is to have the chart component handle mousemove and retreive where the mouse is relative to the data and store that single data point into a property like `mouseOverData` which is then binded to another component, like that top 'tooltip'.  Here's an example of the flattened components (flattened because I would make separate files for each component for ability to reuse in my project):

```
<s:VGroup>
<s:HGroup>
<s:Label text="Some Label: {mouseOverData.someProperty}" />
<s:Label text="Second Label: {mouseOverData.secondProperty}" />
</s:HGroup>
<mx:LineChart mouseMove="calculateMousePositionRelativeToDataAndStoreInMouseOverDataProp(event)" />
</s:VGroup>
```